# scp to pfsense not working

Tags: pfsense, scp

When ever I try to scp a file from pfsense I get back what appears to be the help for pfsense's scp:

```
scp admin@fw:/tmp/test /tmp/
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use root@ instead of admin@.

---

P.S.: Yes I know that ssh works fine with admin. No I'm not joking.